# Redirect Sinatra request changing method and body

Tags: rest, redirect, sinatra

Is there a way to handle a GET request on Sinatra and make a PATCH request with a different body on the same server? User makes a request `GET /clean_beautiful_api` and server redirects it to `PATCH /dirty/clogged_api_url_1?crap=2 "{request_body: 1}"`?

I want to clean up legacy API without interfering with the functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, the easiest way is to extract the block used for the `patch` into a helper:

```
patch "/dirty/clogged_api_url_1"
  crap= params[:crap]
end
```

to:

```
helpers do
  def patch_instead( params={} )
    # whatever you want to do in here
    crap= params[:crap]
  end
end

get "/clean_beautiful_api" do
  patch_instead( params.merge(request_body: 1) )
end


patch "/dirty/clogged_api_url_1"
  patch_instead( params )
end
```

Or you could use a lambda…

```
Patch_instead = ->( params={} ) {
  # whatever you want to do in here
  crap= params[:crap]
}

get "/clean_beautiful_api" do
  Patch_instead.call( params.merge(request_body: 1) )
end

# you get the picture
```

the main thing is to extract the method to somewhere else and then call it.

---

Edit: You can also [trigger another route internally using the Rack interface](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Triggering%20Another%20Route) via `call`.

Comment: Well this approach is an obvious one, but the code I'm working with is  so complex that extracting this functionality will lead to a truck of crap unloading on my head. So I am looking for more of a method to put a request into Rack's/Sinatra's query processing queue.

Comment: @Anton have you looked at [triggering another route via call](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Triggering%20Another%20Route)?

Comment: Can you post it as a separate answer so I can accept it? Also, this does look much better but raises absurd and illogical error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547001/calling-sinatra-from-sinatra-produces-results-different-from-external-request

Comment: @Anton I've tagged it on to the end of this answer.

Comment: On to the next issue then.