# Calling Sinatra from Sinatra produces results different from external request

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

Following my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15500759/redirect-sinatra-request-changing-method-and-body/15507611?noredirect=1#comment22022912_15507611).
So I am trying to do a smart redirect using this:

```
get "/category/:id/merge" do
    #... setting @catalog_id and category
    call env.merge("PATH_INFO" => "/catalog/#{@catalog_id}/category/#{category.id}", "REQUEST_METHOD"=>"PATCH","QUERY_STRING"=>"merge=1")
    status 200
end
```

But when I look in logs, I see something that is not only frustrating but also completely absurd:

```
# this one is from internal call
I, [2013-03-21T15:55:54.382153 #29569]  INFO -- : Processing GET /catalog/1/category/2686/merge
I, [2013-03-21T15:55:54.382239 #29569]  INFO -- : Parameters: {}
...
I, [2013-03-21T15:55:54.394992 #29569]  INFO -- : Processing PATCH /catalog/1/category/2686
I, [2013-03-21T15:55:54.395041 #29569]  INFO -- : Parameters: {"merge"=>"1"}
I, [2013-03-21T15:55:54.395560 #29569]  INFO -- : Processed PATCH /catalog/1/category/2686?merge=1 with status code 404
I, [2013-03-21T15:55:54.395669 #29569]  INFO -- : Processed GET /catalog/1/category/2686/merge with status code 200

# this one is a direct request
I, [2013-03-21T15:56:36.246535 #29588]  INFO -- : Processing PATCH /catalog/1/category/2686
I, [2013-03-21T15:56:36.246629 #29588]  INFO -- : Parameters: {"merge"=>"1"}
...
I, [2013-03-21T15:56:36.286216 #29588]  INFO -- : Processed PATCH /catalog/1/category/2686?merge=1 with status code 204
```

And the body of internal 404 request is just Sinatra's standard 404 error page. How the hell can he tell me straight in the eye that he doesn't know this route if I caught him serving exactly the same URL with acceptable 204?

**UPDATE**
It gets even more exciting when I change REQUEST_METHOD to GET - works like a charm.

```
I, [2013-03-21T17:09:37.718756 #3141]  INFO -- : Processing GET /catalog/1/category/2686/merge
I, [2013-03-21T17:09:37.718838 #3141]  INFO -- : Parameters: {}
...
I, [2013-03-21T17:09:37.735632 #3141]  INFO -- : Processing GET /catalog/1/category/2686
I, [2013-03-21T17:09:37.735678 #3141]  INFO -- : Parameters: {"merge"=>"1"}
...
I, [2013-03-21T17:09:37.773033 #3141]  INFO -- : Processed GET /catalog/1/category/2686?merge=1 with status code 200
I, [2013-03-21T17:09:37.773143 #3141]  INFO -- : Processed GET /catalog/1/category/2686/merge with status code 200
```

Comment: Is the internal request via GET also using the QUERY_STRING key?

Comment: yep, just changet the REQUEST_METHOD parameter

Comment: As you can see by looking at [the source for the latest version of Sinatra](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.4.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1380), PATCH is implemented exactly the same as GET, so something else is different. Which version of Ruby and Sinatra are you using, and which application server?

Comment: Uhm, it doesn't look so. I would say that all methods except GET are implemented in the same way, GET is somewhat different

Comment: Ruby is 1.9.2p180, Sinatra is 1.3.2, server is Thin 1.4.1

Comment: The only thing that is different is that part about conditions, I'm fairly sure that's to stop it being cleared by the `get` so that the `head` declaration can also use it. I'm also wondering how a GET works if you don't have a route declared for it. Does a HEAD or a POST work too?

Comment: `head` works and `post` does not. Clearly, some of the routes are defined at the point and their results are exactly as expected. POST,PATCH and PUT on the other hand are getting cut somewhere within Rack, I suppose, ending their journey with 404 error

Comment: Well, I suppose GET would work as you've defined it to call the PATCH! :) I'm surprised it doesn't go into an infinite loop. If you want to debug it, I'd suggest using [Pry Debugger](https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger), or just `warn env.inspect` inside the relevant routes and watch what happens to the env.

Comment: Try `call env.merge("PATH_INFO" => "#{@catalog_id}/category/#{category.id}", "REQUEST_METHOD"=>"PATCH","QUERY_STRING"=>"merge=1")`. I think the [SCRIPT_PATH may still be prepended by the Rack router even via the call](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/rack-devel/iaeMgi1Nl30/925GWCVCZF0J) (I see "catalog" is not declared in the route's path), but the logs may not reflect it.

Comment: Do you have a patch route?